# jQuery fade content + change div

Tags: jquery, html, fade

I have this little thingy:
http://jsfiddle.net/7hqyq/

And since I'm new to jQuery I'd like to know how to change the background color of the selected square (and thus of the first square on loading the page). And how to fade in/out the content text of the details div.

Thanks in advance ;)

HTML:

```
<div class="square" contentId="c1"></div>
<div class="square" contentId="c2"></div>
<div class="square" contentId="c3"></div>
<div class="square" contentId="c4"></div>

<div id="details">Content for div 1</div>

<div style="display: none" id="c1"> Content for div 1</div>
<div style="display: none" id="c2"> Content for div 2</div>
<div style="display: none" id="c3"> Content for div 3</div>
<div style="display: none" id="c4"> Content for div 4</div>
```

CSS:

```
.square{
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
margin: 10px;
float: left;
background: #CCC;
}

#details{
width: 380px;
height: 100px;
margin: 10px;
float: left;
background: #999;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".square").on("click", function() { 
    var id= $(this).attr("contentId");
    $("#details").html($("#" + id).html());
});
```

Comment: `contentId` is an invalid attribute, Use `data-contentid=""` (!lowercase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this. It doesn't fades your background just changes the text: http://jsfiddle.net/7hqyq/2/

```
$('.square:first').css('background-color', 'red');
$(".square").on("click", function() { 
var id= 'Content for div ' + $(this).attr("contentId");
$('#details').fadeOut(function(){
    $(this).text(id).fadeIn();
})
});
```

I also made so it sets background color to red, and then changes it depending on which div you clicked on. (is that what you mean right?)

Comment: Great, that works great.. on JSFiddle, however sadly enough I can't get it to work in my browser... really can't find out why not. Do you know why? This is the html-doc:
http://payitforwardarnhem.nl/help.txt

Comment: it's really simple. First you forgot to include $(document).ready(function(){ your function here }); and script is executing before page loads. If you do not want to include these words, you need to move your script to the end of your HTML file. Next problem is that you are using hosted library for jQuery - for this to work you need to host your page on a server NOT just save it as HTML file on your computer (I use WAMP server), otherwise you need to download full jQuery library to your computer and include it as a regular script: <script src='your file location'></script>

Comment: You're my hero :P document.ready.. that's basically lesson 1 and I'm never going to forget that anymore ;)
(and I had it uploaded as a .html file on a server, just the .txt for easy access)
It works like a charm now :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is this:
 **[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7hqyq/8/)**

```
function fader(i){
    $('#details >div').stop().fadeTo(400,0)  // All
    .eq(!i?i:$(this).index()).fadeTo(400,1); // indexed one
}

$(".square").on("click", fader );
```

<sup>You can also immediately call a fade on an element by passing to `fader` an index number ie: `fader(0);` (see demo)</sup>

Having this simplified HTML markup:

```
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>

<div id="details">
    <div> Content for div 1</div>
    <div> Content for div 2</div>
    <div> Content for div 3</div>
    <div> Content for div 4</div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
.square{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    background: #CCC;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#details{
    width: 380px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    clear:both;
    float: left;
    background:#999;
}
#details > div{
    position:absolute;
    width: 380px;
    height: 100px;
    display:none;
}
```

BTW `contentId` is an invalid attribute. If you really need to handle custom attributes than go for `data-*` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$(".square").on("click", function() { 
    var id= $(this).attr("contentId");
    $(this).css('background','red');
    $('#details').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(this).html($("#" + id).html()).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EFbtj/

Note that this fades the gray background out/in as well. If you want to prevent that, wrap the div in a wrapper div that has the background.

Also, you can replace `$(this).css('background','red');` with $(this).addClass('yourClassName');` if you prefer to use a class instead of adding inline css for the background.

Comment: That's already a big help. But is it possible to have the first square red on load and have the other squares become grey again when another one is active?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.nav-link').css('background-color', '#ececec');
$('#display-content').html($('#content-01').html());    
$('.nav-link').on('click', function() {
$('.nav-link').css('background-color', '#ececec');
var navLinkId = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);
$(this).css('background-color', '#dadada');
$('#display-content').fadeOut('slow', function() {
$('#display-content').html($('#content-' + navLinkId).html()).fadeIn('slow');
});
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="display-content"></div>
<div id="nav-container">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav-link" id="nav-01">01</li>
        <li class="nav-link" id="nav-02">02</li>
        <li class="nav-link" id="nav-03">03</li>
        <li class="nav-link" id="nav-04">04</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content-container" id="content-01">
    <p>Content layer 01</p>
</div>
<div class="content-container" id="content-02">
    <p>Content layer 02</p>
</div>
<div class="content-container" id="content-03">
    <p>Content layer 03</p>
</div>
<div class="content-container" id="content-04">
    <p>Content layer 04</p>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/portashqipe/0a35cLwk/